# tkinter's filedialog.askopenfilename() dialog box won't open

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to take an image as input from the user.  For this, I am using **tkinter **library. Specifically, the `filedialog.askopenfilename()` method.

1. I am using jupyter notebook, and have also tried running the notebook in vscode with same results
2. python version is 3.11.4
3. tkinter version is 8.6. The code is as follows,
4. Windows 11

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
filePath = filedialog.askopenfile()
```

But the dialog box doesn't open, the program freezes(keeps running endlessly) whenever I execute this. It worked fine the first time(both in jupyter and vscode), but since then I have not been able to make it work. I have also tried using `askopenfile()` and found no success. From what I have seen online, this seems like a common issue([A discussion on the issue. No resolution](https://bugs.python.org/issue38974).

Is there a solution to this problem?

Since the method is not working, if someone could tell me an alternative way to take image as input from the user, that would be really appreciated. I want to design a UI where the user can input images from their system into the program at the press of a button.

Thank you.

Comment: The first paragraph in your question and the title of the question mention `askopenfilename()`, but the code uses `askopenfile()`, so which one you want actually?  Also cannot reproduce your issue when running the posted code in my Windows 7 with Python 3.8.17.

Comment: Worked for me. No issue so far.

Comment: Does this help `file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(%gui tk) ?

Comment: Try calling `root.destroy()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you literally wrote the code you paste us, you're missing:

```
root.mainloop()
```

This allows the Tk root to update correctly and keep track of events that happen in it.

Try to test with the correct code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
filePath = filedialog.askopenfile()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Adding `root.mainloop()` will make the situation worst because the root window is hidden and you has no way to close it after closing the file dialog.

Answer (score 0):

try using:
`filedialog.askopenfilename`